# Victory plugin for Unreal Engine on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, plugins, ubuntu-16.04, unreal-engine4

How can I install Rama's victory plugin for Unreal Engine 4.22 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

If the Plugin is not already compiled for Linux you will most likely need to add its Source Code to your Project and compile it as necessary.